# RailsTutorial.org - Chapter 8 - signed_in? throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to show a navigation bar if the user is signed in.

In my application.html.erb I have the line
`<% if signed_in? %>` - which is causing the error:

`NoMethodError in Static_pages#home`

`undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

```
Extracted source (around line #16):

13:   </head>
14:   <body>
15: 
16:     <% if signed_in? %>
17:      <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
18:       <div class="navbar-inner">
19:         <div class="container">`
```

Here is my **SessionsHelper:**

```
def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    puts 'current_user called'
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies.permanent[:remember_token])
end

def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end
```

My **ApplicationController:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

I can't seem to figure out why `!current_user.nil?` is breaking the page. When I comment out `!current_user.nil?` in the `signed_in?` method can get called without breaking the page. But I obviously don't get the `signed_in` value I was hoping for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exception was raised here: `cookies.permanent[:remember_token]`

so, `cookies.permanent` is nil

---- EDITED

got it,

use `cookies.permanent[:remember_token] =` only for writing, but read it as `cookies[:remember_token]`

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! How did you know that's where the exception was raised?